# Div overlap elements

Tags: css, html

Atm I'm doing my first attempt at a website, recently got a new job which requires me to learn some basic HTML&CSS so for a starters I set myself up to duplicate an exsisting site.

**The question/problem is**:

I wanna make 3 columns at 100% height, the left and right being scaleable to 0 upon downsizing the browserwindow, while the middle column is containing the actual content of the site, min-width at 60%. At lower resolutions im planning on implementing media-things in my css to remove the left n right columns when the resolution goes below a certaint limit.
I've set html&body&all to hight & width 100%.
I'm trying to do something a bit like here: [The site im trying to duplicate](http://www.mols-linien.dk/index.dsp?area=320)
My current attempt can be found here: [My attempt](http://ml.ideside.dk/1213.aspx)

Some code for the lazy ones that don't wanna inspect the site:

```
<div id=all>
    <div id=leftmargin></div>   
    <div id=wrapper>
        <div id=header></div>
        <div id=nav></div>
        <div id=content></div>
        <div id=rightmargin></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since im very new to web development, please excuse me if you need more info.
My problem is in essence that "leftmargin' and 'rightmargin' overlaps the 'wrapper'-div. I'd very much like that to be in the center of the page and then make the margin-divs 'expendable' at lower resolution by css.

I hope I made myself relatively clear, thanks in advance.
Kind regards
Mike

Comment: I'd probably recommend using media queries http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ so when it hits that break point you want just hide the divs or better yet, stack them up so the user is not losing content because their viewport is smaller.

Comment: Have played a bit with mediaqueries(its the @media things in css right? sorry my rookie questions, its my first website ever)
I was worried it would just cut off the margins at a sudden point when users were down-sizing their window, or how does that happen? Im looking for a solution where these 'margins' gradually downsize as a downsize my window so only content is left. Wont it just 'break' at specific points(resolutions, certaint pixel width) if i use mediaqueries?
Ive already set up a mediaquery so it only shows the content of wrapper-div when loaded on a iPhone

Comment: Thx for the input Milche Patern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd avoid using a div for the sole purpose of creating a margin space.  Instead, let your side bar content create the margin you're looking for.  The content is overlapping the margin because it's not contained within the margin div.  You'll need to tweak how the main content is centered by using "margin-left: " the same size as the sidebars or some other way, but it'll improve your overall structure.

As for text overlapping the container at small sizes, remove the "width: 18.8%;" and "white-space: nowrap;" from #lefttop and "max-width: 18.8%;" from #leftnav.  This will let the text be the full width of the gray container on the left, and the words will wrap if the line doesn't fit.

Finally, to get rid of the side bars at small widths, as jerrylow recommended, use

```css
/* screen sizes smaller than 750px apply these styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    #leftnavwrap {
        display: none;
    }
    #shortcut {
        display: none;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo all and thanks for the input, but confused on the minus tho.

Comment: Ive already tried setting up media break points, but wont it make the margins 'suddenly' disappear and adjust, as oppose to the fluid movement i see currently when downsizing my browser.
Sorry for the newbish questions

Comment: It's fine if it suddenly changes while resizing. For a responsive design, the important thing is that it looks good at every screen size (and a pencil-thin side nav at a certain width would not look good).  What it looks like _while resizing_ doesn't really matter, because very few people other than designers watch the layout while dragging the window wider.